# The certificate from domain name is not trusted from mattermost android app

Tags: ssl, certificate, trust, mattermost

I implemented a mattermost server and enabled ssl connection. I can connect to server in browser from my computer and my android phone also from Desktop app. But when i try connect to server from android app , i get this error :
"the certificate from domain name is not trusted " . i searched a lot but i can not find any appropriate solution.did anybody has this problem before ?

mattermost server Version: 5.28.0
;mattermost Build Number: 5.28.1
; mattermost android app version : 1.37.0

Thankyou

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate?